# Can spring data r2dbc validate ddl?

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Is there something like `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`? I want to validate on startup that my ddl matches my models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a feature currently does not exist.